# How to get the real size of the displayed content inside Image component (contain mode)?

Tags: image, react-native

Im trying to match some vectors above a `Image` comonent. In order to do this pixel-perfect, I need to know the size of the image displayed inside `Image` component.

At this point I have the width and height of the component layout, but can't figure out how to calculate the width and height of the image once is inside the `Image` component.

I tried to calculate the following way with the proportions of with and viceversa, but there are some cases (specially vertical image) where this does not work.

```
/*
    Calculate proportional width of displayed image:
    
    photo.width -> width
    photo.height -> x
*/
var x = (width * photo.height) / photo.width;
/*
    calculate proportional height of displayed image:
    
    photo.height -> height
    photo.width -> y
*/
var y = (height * photo.width) / photo.height;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623174/378779) properties of the image element to determine its actual scaled width and height. If for some reason that's not an option, you can do the calculation yourself:

If ( `photo.width` / `photo.height` ) > ( `containerWidth` / `containerHeight` ) then the photo has a wider aspect ratio than the container and can be scaled to fit full-width in the container, with letterboxing (blank space above and below). The new width and height of the photo is:

```
newPhotoWidth = containerWidth
newPhotoHeight = containerWidth * ( photo.height / photo.width )
```

For example, if the container is 500x400 and the photo is 300x50:

```
newPhotoWidth = 500
newPhotoHeight = 83.33 // i.e. 500 * ( 50 / 300 )
```

If ( `photo.width` / `photo.height` ) > ( `containerWidth` / `containerHeight` ) then the photo has a narrower aspect ratio than the container and can be scaled to fit full-height in the container, with letterboxing on the left and right (as shown in your example image). The new width and height of the photo is:

```
newPhotoWidth = containerHeight * ( photo.width / photo.height )
newPhotoHeight = containerHeight
```

For example, if the container is 500x400 and the photo is 50x300:

```
newPhotoHeight = 66.66  // i.e. 400 * ( 50 / 300 )
newPhotoWidth = 400
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wrong when calculating the size of the image but this is perfect!